# jquery make div appear when clicked href clicked on

Tags: jquery

```
#tabs-1 {
    display: none;
}    

#tabs-2 {
    display: none;
}

#tabs-3 {
    display: none;
}

<script type="text/javascript">    
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $(this).click(function () {    
              var a = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
              $(a).show();
          });
      }); 
</script>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div class="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>            
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <h2>Content heading 1</h2>
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Doin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
      <h2>Content heading 2</h2>
      <p>Morbi tfhgdfahsdh</p>
    </div>
  </div>    
</form>
</body>
```

I'm trying to make a simple jquery script that makes these divs appear when i click on the ahref in the ordered list. When i run this code it always displays the first element in the ordered list. I want to display the element that is linked in the hyperlink.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
$('div.tabs > ul > li > a').click(function(e) {
  var id = this.getAttribute('href');
  $(id).toggle();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

This uses the selector `divs.tabs ul li a` to select the anchor tags in question and adds a click handler to them.  On click it will use the `href` attribute as the id of the DOM element which needs to be hidden.  The `e.preventDefault()` line prevents the anchor from it's default action which would be attempting to navigate to it`s`href`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AWPFJ/3/

Comment: How would I make it hide again when a different tab is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

I use a selector to get all anchor-tags that are children of the .tabs class. Within the click-function I use this to refer to the clicked element, and get the value of the href-attribute. That value is then used as the selector to get the right div to show. The click function receive the event as a parameter, which can be used with `.preventDefault()` to make sure that the browser does not follow the link.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.tabs ul li a").click(function (event) {
        var id = $(this).attr("href");
        $(id).show();
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: This would also add the handler to any anchor tags which appeared inside the content section of the page.  I would make the selector more specific to limit it's potential impact

Comment: @JaredPar Agreed, I thought of this as more of an example. He would probably be best of by adding an id to his navigation container, and use that to select on. However, I updated the selector to be a bit more specific in my example.

Answer (score 0):

In short, this should do:

```
$(".tabs").find("a").click(function() {
    $($(this).attr("href")).show();
    return false;
})
```

You should add a "tab" class to all tabs and add the following as well:

```
$(".tabs").find("a").click(function() {
    $(".tab").hide();
    $($(this).attr("href")).show();
    return false;
})
```

Comment: it would hide all tabs, then show the tab you need, but you'd need to add the class="tab" to all your tabs.

Comment: for some reason it isn't working correctly on my default tab (the first element it loads on page load) it shows initially then won't show again when clicked upon.

Comment: This may happen for dynamicly generated tabs, ensure you wrap the generated html within jquery's $(element), for example div.append($('<div id="tab"></div>'))

Answer (score 0):

That's because your script is setting the click handler on the entire document, and the first  is always getting selected as a result of that. Modify your script to set a click handler on the <a> element or the parent <li> itself, retrieve the DIV corresponding to the href attribute value and invoke the show() method on that DIV. I don't have a chance to test, but it would be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click(function () {
        var a = $(this).attr("href");
        $(a).show();
    });
});
```

HTH,
Ashwin